# Use of current division

Tags: current, basic

"Calculate V (across the current source) and the current flowing down through R1."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faD6vV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does the voltage source also produce current, so that the current flowing to the parallel resistors is the sum of 40mA and the current produced by the voltage source? (For knowing which value to input into current division formula)

Comment: No, the current is 40 mA, period. The only real unknown here is how much voltage appears across the current source. Is that enough of a hint to get you started?

Comment: In corollary to Dave Tweed's above comment: there are two ways of looking at it. The voltage source is a zero ohm impedance through which the current produced by the current source flows transparently. Alternatively, the current source is an open circuit (very high impedance) through which the voltage source cannot produce a current.

Comment: @ Kaz Is your explanation valid for those two sources being in parallel? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the voltage source also produce current, so that the current flowing to the parallel resistors is the sum of 40mA and the current produced by the voltage source?

If two components are in series, then the current through them is equal. That means the current through the voltage source is equal to the current through the current source.